How to get the all text inside the pane using python library pywinauto
I am trying to automate filetest.exe using python pywinauto library but I am not able to get the text inside the pane (which is showing in image with yellow box).
Here is my code
from pywinauto import Application

from pywinauto.keyboard import send_keys


app = Application().start(r"C:\Users\test\Documents\FileTest.exe")


dlg = app.window(title_re=".*FileTest.*")

tab_control = dlg['TabControl']
tab_control.select('ReadWrite')

dlg['ReadFile Button'].click()


get_object = dlg[':DataEditor']
get_value = get_object.window_text()
print(f"get_value: {get_value}")


print("Automation complete and operation completed successfully!")

Getting empty for get_value
I have attached the image of filetest.exe and inspect element of filetest.exe



Try Application(backend="uia") instead of Application() which uses "win32" backend. "uia" has more capabilities for wider range of applications. But "pane" is often pain even for "uia", because it is custom control type. And most probably this UI element can't be automated a nice way. Since you use Inspect.exe it already shows you a hierarchy for "uia" backend in fact. No luck. :(

@VasilyRyabov This is not working, Is there any other way?

I've found the source code of FileTest tool. It seems the DataEditor can react on keys including copy to/from clipboard. The necessary code starts from here: https://github.com/ladislav-zezula/FileTest/blob/master/TDataEditor.cpp#L949 So module pywinauto.clipboard can do the job together with method .type_keys(...) which supports key combinations like ^c (means Ctrl+c) or ^v (means Ctrl+v).  Other useful methods and links to their docs are here: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_execution.html#tricks-to-run-automation-on-a-locked-machine
